# Rails show parent data in child index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

[See the code and what I mean in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEWUo.png)

how do i show the parent in the child index page?

An example is the ID number 1,2,3,5 they are the child and their parent is the account name OSCAR. and for the parent THIRD their ID child number is 6 and 7.
I can show the child in the parent show page but I dont know how to display them oppositely.

[like this is working if my parent want to display child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSEiX.png)
 but I want a child index showing all the child and with its parents

Comment: Hi Oscar. Your question is bit hard to understand. Are you wanting to scope your output in the view so that `current_user` can only see his/her remittances and invoices? Or are you wondering why the entries in the columns that you point out aren't there? I'm asking because it seems to me like you're already doing what you want to be doing "Oscar" and "Second" are already displaying in your table.

Comment: all user can see it. what i want is to show all the child in the index, but each child have different parents so i want the parent information also displayed.. the parent information is the account_name so the child being displayed should also have the account_name tied into it which are their parents.

Comment: So, is some of the data populating, like "Oscar" and "second" in the list and you're wondering why the other data is not there? It looks to me like the code `<td><%= remit.invoice.account_name if remit.invoice %></td>` should do the trick.

Comment: as you can see I have that code on there but its not working. what I am getting is the table on the top not the table what I wanted at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a Data integrity issue to me. Open a rails console with `rails c` and then type `Remittance.find_by(id: 4).invoice`, it will either be that is `nil` as the objects aren't properly associated, or `Remittance.find(id: 4).invoice.account_name` will be `""` or `nil`, as that invoice's `account_name` doesn't have anything populating it.

EDIT:
To fix the problem:

You need to associate your database objects in the model with a has_many/belongs_to relationship. With a SQL DB, this is done with a foreign key. Here's the documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: yes you are right, how do i do it the right way then? when I do Invoice.find(1).remittances I can see the child; how do I fix it? Thanks! in order when I do the Remittance.find_by(id: 4).invoice so it wont show up as nil?

Comment: oh i fixed it.. my foreign_key was wrong that is why. thanks alot! I was linking the invoice id to remittance_id.

Comment: Ah! Very good. :-) Yes. Sounds right, I updated my answer too with that info.